# Could someone please explain the code for me?

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, module, boolean

def bhl(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for b in range(3,int(x**0.5 +1)):
        if x % b == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

Don't know if I'm too tired but I really can't figure out what this part of the code does. Can someone please explain it for me:

```
elif x % 2 == 0:
    return False
for b in range(3,int(x**0.5 +1)):
    if x % b == 0:
        return False
else:
    return True
```

Comment: if x is evenly divisible by 2 return false and the next line if x evenly divisible by b return false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks whether x is prime

`x % 2 == 0` checks if x is even, or in other words it has no remainder when you divide it by 2

```
for b in range(3,int(x**0.5 +1)): if x % b == 0: return False
```

This checks from 3 to x/2+1 if there is a number that divides x without remainder.
Previous cases checked 1 and 2, and there is no point in checking whether a number bigger than x/2 divides x without remainder, because there isn't one.